# critical Z-statistic vs sample Z-statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, z-statistic

*A hypothesis that the population mean is less or equal to $x$ should be rejected when the critical Z-statistic is greater than the sample Z-statistic.* $x$ is any number.

1. If $x=5$, the statement is true or false? The answer is false, but **why**?
2. For what values of $x$ the statement is true or false?

I know this is a one-tail hypothesis, but how do I know which tail are we talking about? Or is there some general rule that can answer 2)?

**UPDATE**: I will post the question completely:

> Which of the following statements about hypothesis testing is most
> accurate?
>
> A) A Type I error is rejecting the null hypothesis when it is true,
> and a Type II error is rejecting the alternative hypothesis when it is
> true.
>
> B) A hypothesis that the population mean is less than or equal
> to 5 should be rejected when the critical Z-statistic is greater than
> the sample Z-statistic.
>
> C) A hypothesized mean of 3, a sample mean of
> 6, and a standard error of the sampling means of 2 give a sample
> Z-statistic of 1.5.

The answer is C. I'm trying to understand when B would be true (first understanding when B is true for $x=5$ as in my original question, then understanding when it's true for any value of $x$

Comment: Something is missing. What are the null and alternative hypotheses? When you write $x$, do you mean the sample mean $\bar x?$

Comment: $x$ means any number. The problem doesn't states any specifically about the null and alternative H, it's only true or false.

Comment: (1) and (2) make no sense: could you rephrase them?  What "statement" are they trying to refer to?  What is the meaning of "critical Z-statistic"?  Is it some kind of statistic or is it trying to refer to a *critical value* for the test?

Comment: If we don't know the sample mean and variance, knowing $x$ will not help to answer the first question. It can be true and it can be false

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear we can give it some context.  Let $X_1,...,X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\sigma^2$ known.  To test $H_0: \mu \le 5$ at level $\alpha$ we would compare the observed sample test statistic

$$z=\frac{\bar{x}-5}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$$

to the critical value $z_{1-\alpha}$.  If $z>z_{1-\alpha}$ then $H_0$ is rejected.  Otherwise, $H_0$ is not rejected.

To generalize we would write $H_0: \mu \le \mu_0$ and examine $z=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$.  Nevertheless, if $z>z_{1-\alpha}$ then $H_0$ is rejected.

Option B) above is incorrect because it states that $H_0$ is rejected if $z_{1-\alpha}>z$.  Let me know if I have understood your question correctly and if I have made any mistakes.